# How to make api request from WebController to ApiController in same project?

Tags: laravel

I have WebController and ApiController with the routes Web.php and Api.php

I need to send api request from my WebController to ApiController to collect the api response.

In the postman api request and response is working fine. But when i try with the WebController it's getting cURL timeout.

Below are my codes in WebController and ApiController

In WebController

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

public function profile()
    {
        $apiURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/profile';

        $response = Http::get($apiURL);

        echo $response;
    }
```

In ApiController

```
public function profile()
    {
        return response()->json([
                'message'   => 'Success',
            ], 200);
    }
```

But getting an error in the WebController

[broswer response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ycQN.png)

In Postman and in the browser the api is working

[postman img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyNSq.png)

[browser img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sbo7.png)

How to call api request from Webcontroller to ApiController in the same project with routes Web.php and Api.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you use PHP internal server.

Run another server `php artisan serve --port=7000` and then set the URL to `http://127.0.0.1:7000/api/v1/profile`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in the same server you could call for the function from the `Webcontroller` like in below

```
return (new ApiController())->profile();
```